# phpunit 6.5 hide sql debug output

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there way to hide this debug output which I'm getting during runtime? This is visible in phpunit 6.5, but not for example in version 6.2...

```
PHPUnit 6.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.................................

2018-10-31T09:47:58+00:00 [debug] SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence' AND name != 'geometry_columns' AND name != 'spatial_ref_sys' UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Please don't post links to images.  Put the actual output in the question itself instead.

Comment: @GordonM done...

Comment: That output is not coming from PHPUnit but either from your test code or the code being tested.